# Strange Behavior adding structure with a DateTime value to a List

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain why this exception is thrown when I add an object to a List<>

```
Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime
```

The datetime in the structure is valid and matches whats coming out of the database. Not sure why its throwing the exception when adding to the list.

The code is pretty simple

```
     var returnData = new List<IntelliformMetaData>();
     foreach (DataRow row in ExecuteQuery(command).Rows)
                {
                    //returnData.Add(new IntelliformMetaData()
                    //    {
                    //        header = (byte[])row["header"],
                    //        OprINI = row["initial"].ToString(),
                    //        CreatedTime = (DateTime)row["dt"],
                    //        ID = (int)row["id"],
                    //        FileReason = ""
                    //    });

                    var temp = new IntelliformMetaData();
                    temp.header = (byte[])row["header"];
                    temp.CreatedTime = (DateTime)row["dt"]; <- OK
                    temp.OprINI = row["initial"].ToString();
                    temp.ID = (int)row["id"];
                    temp.FileReason = "";

                    returnData.Add(temp); <- Exception

                }
```

Structure

```
private struct IntelliformMetaData
{
    public long ID;
    public string OprINI;
    public string FileReason;
    public DateTime CreatedTime;
    public byte[] header;
}
```

Comment: The exception seems to contradict your "valid" structure.  What does the debugger tell you is the value of `row["dt"]`?

Comment: make sure the date is in the order of year, month, day.

Comment: Is the column type in the database actually of type DateTime or is it Varchar?

Comment: the value of row["dt"] = {4/22/2016 3:11:43 PM}. casting row["dt"] to a datetime is working just fine http://i369.photobucket.com/albums/oo132/mrpyrochris/DateError.png. The image shows the value being stored in the datetime value in the structure. I would think you would get an exception during the cast if the value of row["dt"] was the problem. For this issue its happening when being added to a list

Comment: @exceptionthrown its a DateTime

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with your code.  The temp object is getting added to the list.

Comment: @LarsTech Super strange. i have a few other methods that do nearly the same thing without issue which is why im scratching my head. I even tried DateTime.Parse(row["dt"].ToString) into a value and setting that into the structure. Still get the exception when adding it.

Comment: So just an update to this. If i dont set the ID value everything works OK.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a mutable struct (as you are currently doing), make it immutable and assign the values when constructing the struct. Mutable structs can have weird issues and this seems like a potential cause for what you are experiencing.

So if you change your struct code to:

```
private struct IntelliformMetaData
{
    public readonly long ID;
    public readonly string OprINI;
    public readonly string FileReason;
    public readonly DateTime CreatedTime;
    public readonly byte[] header;

    public IntelliformMetaData(long pId, string pOprINI, string pFileReason, DateTime pCreatedTime, byte[] pHeader)
    {
        this.ID = pId;
        this.OprINI = pOprINI;
        this.FileReason = pFileReason;
        this.CreatedTime = pCreatedTime;
        this.header = pHeader;
    }
}
```

And then change where you create it to:

```
var temp = new IntelliformMetaData((int)row["id"]
            , row["initial"].ToString()
            , ""
            , (DateTime)row["dt"]
            , (byte[])row["header"]);

returnData.Add(temp);
```

Comment: Copied your code and still getting the same error ;-(. Also tried to Make IntelliformMetaData a class and still get the same problem